# SwiftyStoreKit parse receipt

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, in-app-purchase

In the documentation for SwiftStoreKit it is written that the Receipt can be obtained using

```
let appleValidator = AppleReceiptValidator (service: .production, sharedSecret: "your-shared-secret")
SwiftyStoreKit.verifyReceipt (using: appleValidator, forceRefresh: false) {result in
     switch result {
     case .success (let receipt):
         print ("Verify receipt success: \ (receipt)")
     case .error (let error):
         print ("Verify receipt failed: \ (error)")
     }
}
```

however, I tried to parse and insert into the model but nothing worked. Can anyone help?
need to parse latest_receipt_info or in_app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use this library you need to implement your own logic to do the local verification of receipt.

according to README from this library

> You should implement your secure logic by validating your receipt
>   locally, or sending the encrypted receipt data and validating it in
>   your server.
>
> Local receipt validation is not implemented (see issue #101 for
>   details).

This may help you https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW2

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned in their documentation [here](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit#receipt-verification)

Use this method to get the updated receipt:

```
SwiftyStoreKit.fetchReceipt(forceRefresh: true) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let receiptData):
        let encryptedReceipt = receiptData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
        print("Fetch receipt success:\n\(encryptedReceipt)")
    case .error(let error):
        print("Fetch receipt failed: \(error)")
    }
}
```